# Q: How to speed up meteor builds/installing packages?

Tags: meteor

I'm quite new to Meteor so am not sure what information I can provide to help you guys understand what the problem is. But every time I try to run my meteor apps, or whenever I add a package/library etc the builds and package installations take absolutely ages - up to 10 minutes. I'm really not sure why this is but it is very frustrating and I end up getting distracted in the time that I wait.

The version of meteor I am using is @1.7.0.4

Meteor packages:

```
meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.5.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze 
views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive 
programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.4.1   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.3.4    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older 
browsers
ecmascript@0.11.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app 
code
shell-server@0.3.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor 
shell` command

insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for 
prototyping)
materialize:materialize
aldeed:collection2-core
momentjs:moment
aldeed:autoform

Packages.json:

{
  "name": "hotel",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "run lint --silent",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "@meteorjs/eslint-config-meteor"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@meteorjs/eslint-config-meteor": "^1.0.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-meteor": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-meteor": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please add some anonymized specs of your hardware (cpu, ram, drive) so we can include or exclude hardware as a cause for this issue. Please also add the content of your `package.json` and your `.meteor/packages` files. Usually Meteor should be not that slow on somehow up to date hardware.

Comment: Are you using windows? If so, Antivirus has a very strong effect on build times (4-10x longer). Add exclusions for everything meteor/node related

Comment: I'm not, I'm on Mac OS High Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: On a Mac, click the apple icon at the top left and click "About this Mac". The specs should be there. For builds, you'll find that CPUs with single core high clock rates build faster since it's single threaded. E.g, a dual core 4 GHz would build faster than a 2GHz quad.

As a debug check, try doing a `meteor reset`. *warning: this will clear your meteor db if you're using the internal mongo db that Meteor kicks off.